# Reputation by action

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently we can see the reputation by post, time and graph.

[image]

I think it would be great if we can also see the reputation by action.

**Actions**

```
Edits
Upvotes
Downvotes
Question Accepts
Answer Accepts
Bounty Offers
Bounty Earnings
```

Comment: Don't forget bounties.

Comment: ...And sockpuppetry.

Comment: Any consideration for my feature-request?